# how to add pre and post integration phase to maven-failsafe-plugin

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, pom.xml, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am having a netty application server need to be started at the **pre-integration-test phase** and stop it during the **post-integration-test phase** for the testing purpose of IntegrationTests. I had used `maven-failsafe-plugin`. But i don't know to execute the main class during the pre-integration-test phase and how to stop the server after the execution. Also my main class reside in the sub module of the project. I had created a profile for running the IntegrationTest in the parent pom.

```
     <profile>
        <id>integration-tests</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>application_module1</module>
        </modules>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.14.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-source</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>src/it/java</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-resource</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                             <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, because it is similar to my recent question about doing the same thing with an [embedded postgres instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182104/how-to-use-the-embedded-postgresql-server-java-component-as-a-separate-service).

As per @Tunaki suggestion to me, and from my research, I do not believe there is an easy way for you to have the `maven-failsafe-plugin` initiate a server start process without customizing/forking the failsafe plugin code itself (which I would not recommend).

Perhaps a better option is doing something like I am doing for the my postgres-embedded service need: creating a new, fairly simple plugin for initializing the netty service. Refer to @Tunaki's selected [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182104/how-to-use-the-embedded-postgresql-server-java-component-as-a-separate-service?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

Based on @Tunaki advice and following this fairly easy-to-follow [maven-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) guide I have created a small Java (Maven-plugin) project that consists of:

- the plugin pom (using the maven-plugin-plugin 3.4 build plugin)
- My java service class that contains the code to initiate, maintain the state of the server process and **Stop** the server process.
- Two Mojo (Java classes) on for my Start Process and one for my stop process that notably are annotated like this:

  @Mojo(name = "startpostgres", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PRE_INTEGRATION_TEST)
  public class StartPostgresMojo extends AbstractMojo

My plugin pom starts like this:

```
<groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>postgres-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

It sounds like doing something like this with your netty app server can work for you.

The other thing you might be able to do is fork the [maven cargo plugin](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+plugin.html) and try to add your own support for netty app server, since that is ***not*** of the current supported containers for cargo